# How can I run a `node fs` function within a Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am minifying my .css with `gulp-cssnano` and I would alse like to rename the css file from `main.css` to `main.min.css`.

To that affect I have created:

```
gulp.task('cssnano', async function() {
  return gulp.src('./dist/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));

    fs.rename('./dist/css/main.css', '/dist/css/main.min.css', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('File Renamed.');
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work - the `fs` function doesn't fire at all.

I also broke it off into it's own function:

```
gulp.task('cssnano', async function() {
  return gulp.src('./dist/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
    .pipe(renameToMin());
});

function renameToMin() {
  fs.rename('./dist/css/main.css', '/dist/css/main.min.css', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File Renamed.');
  });
}
```

But again just got an error with no results:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

[`series()`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series) will allow you to chain tasks.

```
const { rename } = require('node:fs/promises')
const { series } = require('gulp')

function cssnanoBuild() {
  return gulp.src('./dist/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'))
});

async function cssnanoRenameToMin() {
  await rename('./dist/css/main.css', '/dist/css/main.min.css')
  console.log('File Renamed.');
}

exports.cssnano = series(cssnanoBuild, cssnanoRenameToMin)
```